# rabbitmq, not able to send message to specific queue

Tags: php, rabbitmq, php-amqplib

I'm trying to deliver a message to an exchange and then to a specific queue.

```
    $conn = new AMQPConnection(RABBITMQ_NODE_IP_ADDRESS, RABBITMQ_PORT, RABBITMQ_USERNAME, RABBITMQ_PASSWORD, RABBITMQ_VHOST);
    $queue = RABBITMQ_QUEUE_CSV;
    $exchange = RABBITMQ_EXCHANGE;
    $ch = $conn->channel();
    $ch->exchange_declare($exchange, 'direct', false, true, false);
    $ch->queue_declare($queue, false, true, false, false);
    $ch->queue_bind($queue, $exchange, $queue);
    $msg = new AMQPMessage(json_encode($params), array('content_type' => 'text/plain', 'delivery_mode' => 2));
    $ch->basic_publish($msg, $exchange);
    $ch->close();
    $conn->close();
    $status = Array("status" => "Job queued");
```

the type of exchange is 'direct', I have then added a Queue named 'foo_bar' and as 'Routing key' I've used the same 'foo_bar' string.

Just reading the documentation http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-four-php.html I cannot understand where I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: go to the rabbitmq manager interface , click the exchange you want and assign your queue to the exchange if it is not assigned. Also can you normally add a message to a queue without interfering with the exchanges?

Comment: Hi, I've already did what you suggest and if I do so, no message is published. it silently fails

Comment: But it happens only when you are using an exchange, or it happens also on a simple publish to queue?

Comment: I can publish to any queue, it happens when I try to specify a routing key

Comment: I recently had similar problems with exchanges, but if I remember right I entered the manager > exchange, and assigned routing key and queue.
Take a look on that. I will check it out tomorrow at my office to see the exact issue and solution. In general an exchange is mapping a message to a queue by the routing key, but I had to assign it also manually through the manager.

Comment: thanks! let me know, I've almost finished the walls to bash my head on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here: `$ch->queue_bind($queue, $exchange, $queue);` you bind the queue using the `$queue` routing key.

Here: `$ch->basic_publish($msg, $exchange);` you publish a message with an empty routing key. For the message to reach the queue, the routing key on the binding and on the message publication must match

Comment: ouch, I'll look into it tomorrow morning. thanks a lot

Comment: Thank you very much, of course it works and now that you have explained where I got it wrong it makes sense.  Cheers!